# Forward "local mails" to external SMTP server

Tags: mail, smtp

I have a standalone 18.04 server just for running a simple LAMP website. Sometimes when I log in to the server I get notified that I have mail (like cron/at job outputs), and then I read them using mutt. The problem is that I get to know their existence only when I log in. Is there a configuration somewhere to automatically forward these local mails to my company email address so that I really get active notifications?

p.s. Sendmail is also installed but the only configuration I made to it is `` define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.mycompany.com')dnl `` in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`, so that my PHP application can send emails through SMTP server with just a few lines of codes.

Comment: What is in `/etc/aliases`?

Answer (score 0):

If you'r Sendmail/Postfix is configured and running.

Just insert/replace in `/etc/aliases`

```
root: email@yourcompany.com
```

Comment: IMHO it is better to keep local copy too. `root: email@yourcompany.com, local_account_name`

Comment: My /etc/aliases is like `root: my_local_account,my_company_account@mycompany.com (new line) my_local_account: my_local_account,my_company_account@mycompany.com`, and I ran `sudo newaliases` after editing this file. However none of the mails get sent to my company mailbox, though mails for root do get sent to my_local_account. Just now I tested my PHP application, which sends mail to users as usual, so it seems that the SMART_HOST setting in sendmail.mc as mentioned in my original post does work.